# Group array by values php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to group an array by it's values. Below is my array:

```
$array = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'name' => 'John Doe',
            'age' => '36',
            'code' => '437',                           
            'group' => '1000',
        ),
    1 => Array
        (
            'name' => 'John Doe',
            'age' => '36',
            'code' => '437',                           
            'group' => '7777',
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            'name' => 'John Doe',
            'age' => '36',
            'code' => '437',                           
            'group' => '7777',
        ),
    3 => Array
        (
            'name' => 'John Doe',
            'age' => '36',
            'code' => '437',                           
            'group' => '4000',
        ),

    4 => Array
        (
            'name' => 'John Doe',
            'age' => '36',
            'code' => '437',                           
            'group' => '4000',
        ),

    5 => Array
        (
            'name' => 'John Doe',
            'age' => '36',
            'code' => '437',                           
            'group' => '5000',
        ),

    6 => Array
        (
            'name' => 'John Doe',
            'age' => '36',
            'code' => '437',                           
            'group' => '6000',
        ),

    7 => Array
        (
            'name' => 'John Doe',
            'age' => '36',
            'code' => '437',                           
            'group' => '6000',
        ),
);
```

I have tried below:

```
$result = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $record) {
        if (!isset($result[$record['code']])) {
            $result[$record['code']] = array(
                'name' => $record['name'],
                'age' => $record['age'],
                'groups' => array(array($record['code'], $record['group'])),
            );
        }
        else {
            $result[$record['code']]['groups'][] = array($record['code'],$record['group']);
        }
    }
    $result = array_values($result);

    print_r($result);
```

And I am getting:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => John Doe
            [age] => 36
            [groups] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 437
                            [1] => 1000
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 437
                            [1] => 7777
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 437
                            [1] => 7777
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 437
                            [1] => 4000
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 437
                            [1] => 4000
                        )

                    [5] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 437
                            [1] => 5000
                        )

                    [6] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 437
                            [1] => 6000
                        )

                    [7] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 437
                            [1] => 6000
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Now, I want my array to be grouped by the values of group 7777, 1000 and others(all others group values):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => John Doe
            [age] => 36
            [7777] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 437
                            [1] => 7777
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 437
                            [1] => 7777
                        )
                )
            [6000] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 437
                            [1] => 6000
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 437
                            [1] => 6000
                        )
                )
            [others] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 437
                            [1] => 1000
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 437
                            [1] => 4000
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 437
                            [1] => 4000
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 437
                            [1] => 5000
                        )
                )

        )

)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the point of the first array level? You can have multiple "name" / "age" ?

Comment: yes you are right.

Comment: I'm right for which point? The first level is useless or you can have multiple name / age?

Comment: I can have multiple name/age.

Comment: I post an anwser that looks like what you want, but I don't get the point of adding the "code" value multiple time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
// Create a new array
$result = array();

// Loop through your array
foreach ($array as $value) {
    // Create a key that start at 0
    $i = 0;
    // Test if $result[0] exist : if yes, you have data, else you have nothing
    if (isset($result[$i])) {
        do {
            // Check if the 'name' is new : if yes, $i++ to check next name
            if ($result[$i]['name'] !== $value['name']) $i++;
            // If you find similar name, stop here
            else break;
        } while (isset($result[$i]));
    // Just add $result[0] with name and age value
    } else {
        $result[$i] = array (
            'name' => $value['name'],
            'age'  => $value['age']
        );
    }
    // Now you know the index of result you need to work with
    // Just add a new code / group array to your code index
    $result[$i][$value['group']][] = array($value['code'], $value['group']);
}
```

If you do `var_dump($result);` the output is :

```
array (size=1)
0 => 
  array (size=7)
    'name' => string 'John Doe' (length=8)
    'age' => string '36' (length=2)
    1000 => 
      array (size=1)
        0 => 
          array (size=2)
            0 => string '437' (length=3)
            1 => string '1000' (length=4)
    7777 => 
      array (size=2)
        0 => 
          array (size=2)
            0 => string '437' (length=3)
            1 => string '7777' (length=4)
        1 => 
          array (size=2)
            0 => string '437' (length=3)
            1 => string '7777' (length=4)
    4000 => 
      array (size=2)
        0 => 
          array (size=2)
            0 => string '437' (length=3)
            1 => string '4000' (length=4)
        1 => 
          array (size=2)
            0 => string '437' (length=3)
            1 => string '4000' (length=4)
    5000 => 
      array (size=1)
        0 => 
          array (size=2)
            0 => string '437' (length=3)
            1 => string '5000' (length=4)
    6000 => 
      array (size=2)
        0 => 
          array (size=2)
            0 => string '437' (length=3)
            1 => string '6000' (length=4)
        1 => 
          array (size=2)
            0 => string '437' (length=3)
            1 => string '6000' (length=4)
```

---

**EDIT :**

To get only group value equal to `7777` and `6000` replace

```
$result[$i][$value['group']][] = array($value['code'], $value['group']);
```

by

```
$group_value = $value['group'] == "7777" || $value['group'] == "6000" ? $value['group'] : "Others";
$result[$i][$group_value][] = array($value['code'], $value['group']);
```

Now the output of `var_dump($result);` is :

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
  array (size=5)
    'name' => string 'John Doe' (length=8)
    'age' => string '36' (length=2)
    'Others' => 
      array (size=4)
        0 => 
          array (size=2)
            0 => string '437' (length=3)
            1 => string '1000' (length=4)
        1 => 
          array (size=2)
            0 => string '437' (length=3)
            1 => string '4000' (length=4)
        2 => 
          array (size=2)
            0 => string '437' (length=3)
            1 => string '4000' (length=4)
        3 => 
          array (size=2)
            0 => string '437' (length=3)
            1 => string '5000' (length=4)
    7777 => 
      array (size=2)
        0 => 
          array (size=2)
            0 => string '437' (length=3)
            1 => string '7777' (length=4)
        1 => 
          array (size=2)
            0 => string '437' (length=3)
            1 => string '7777' (length=4)
    6000 => 
      array (size=2)
        0 => 
          array (size=2)
            0 => string '437' (length=3)
            1 => string '6000' (length=4)
        1 => 
          array (size=2)
            0 => string '437' (length=3)
            1 => string '6000' (length=4)
```

Is it what you want?

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in my question. Thanks for your quick response. :) It almost solved my problem. Actually, I want only three groups 7777, 6000 and Others. Othere will contain the group values of 1000, 4000 and 5000).

Comment: 7777 and 6000 are static? They won't change?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your business logic is, but your data storage design is not optimal.  Redundant levels and values can and should be removed as a matter of best practices.  That advice aside, Mickael's solution will possibly let you down if your input array is not pre-sorted on `code` values and you have more than one `code` value.

The process is very straight forward.  Use `code` values as temporary unique keys in your output array.  If dealing with the first occurrence of a `code` value, set the `name` and `age` elements.  On every iteration, add a new subarray to the output array based on the `code` value and the `group` value condition.  When the loop finishes, reindex the output array with `array_values()`.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/O8DqO))

```
$array = [
    ['name' => 'John Doe', 'age' => '36', 'code' => '437', 'group' => '1000'],
    ['name' => 'John Doe', 'age' => '36', 'code' => '437', 'group' => '7777'],
    ['name' => 'John Doe', 'age' => '36', 'code' => '437', 'group' => '7777'],
    ['name' => 'John Doe', 'age' => '36', 'code' => '437', 'group' => '4000'],
    ['name' => 'John Doe', 'age' => '36', 'code' => '437', 'group' => '4000'],
    ['name' => 'John Doe', 'age' => '36', 'code' => '437', 'group' => '5000'],
    ['name' => 'John Doe', 'age' => '36', 'code' => '437', 'group' => '6000'],
    ['name' => 'John Doe', 'age' => '36', 'code' => '437', 'group' => '6000']
];

foreach ($array as $row) {
    if (!isset($result[$row['code']])) {
        $result[$row['code']] = ['name' => $row['name'], 'age' => $row['age']];
    }
    $result[$row['code']][in_array($row['group'], ['7777','6000']) ? $row['group'] : 'others'][] = [$row['code'], $row['group']];
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'John Doe',
    'age' => '36',
    'others' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        0 => '437',
        1 => '1000',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        0 => '437',
        1 => '4000',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        0 => '437',
        1 => '4000',
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        0 => '437',
        1 => '5000',
      ),
    ),
    7777 => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        0 => '437',
        1 => '7777',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        0 => '437',
        1 => '7777',
      ),
    ),
    6000 => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        0 => '437',
        1 => '6000',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        0 => '437',
        1 => '6000',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method that heavily relies on array_intersect if I may say it myself.
This is to make sure the number of loops is keept as low as possible.

I loop only the unique names, and the unique groups within that name.

```
$names = array_column($array, "name");
$groups = array_column($array, "group");

foreach(array_unique($names) as $name){
    $intersects = array_intersect_key($array, array_intersect($names, [$name]));
    $new[$name] = ["name" => $name, "age" => end($intersects)["age"]]; // Create the start of the array
    foreach(array_unique($groups) as $group){ // loop only unique groups
        $intersects = array_intersect_key($array, array_intersect($groups, [$group])); // find matching arrays with this group
        foreach($intersects as $int){
            $temp = array_diff($int, ["name" => $new[$name]["name"], "age" => $new[$name]["age"]]); // remove the name and age from the matching array and place them in 6000/7777 or others
            if($temp["group"] == "6000" || $temp["group"] == "7777"){
                $new[$name][$group][] = $temp; 
            }else{
                $new[$name]["others"][] = $temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
var_dump($new);
```

output:

```
array(1) {
  ["John Doe"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(8) "John Doe"
    ["age"]=>
    string(2) "36"
    ["others"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["code"]=>
        string(3) "437"
        ["group"]=>
        string(4) "1000"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["code"]=>
        string(3) "437"
        ["group"]=>
        string(4) "4000"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(2) {
        ["code"]=>
        string(3) "437"
        ["group"]=>
        string(4) "4000"
      }
      [3]=>
      array(2) {
        ["code"]=>
        string(3) "437"
        ["group"]=>
        string(4) "5000"
      }
    }
    [7777]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["code"]=>
        string(3) "437"
        ["group"]=>
        string(4) "7777"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["code"]=>
        string(3) "437"
        ["group"]=>
        string(4) "7777"
      }
    }
    [6000]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["code"]=>
        string(3) "437"
        ["group"]=>
        string(4) "6000"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["code"]=>
        string(3) "437"
        ["group"]=>
        string(4) "6000"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/jCKk7

EDIT changed 1000 to 6000 as read in comments to other answer.

Comment: Again, your solution appears over-engineered and is very difficult to comprehend.  All of those `array_` functions are leading to lots of iteration.  My stance is not about micro-optimization, it is a matter of directness and readability.